# Программное, автоматизированное нажатие кнопки в другом приложении

Tags: android, автоматизация

Возникла задача в создании взаимодействия моего android приложения с чужим приложением, которое само по себе не предусматривает такого воздействия. Конкретно, мне нужно чтобы в одном (чужом) приложении каждые 10 минут нажималась одна и та же кнопка. Есть ли возможность вообще сделать такое или это совершенно невозможно? Прошу у вас любую информацию о таком роде взаимодействий приложений и служб в android.

Comment: без вариантов, нельзя никак повлиять на другое приложение, если оно само того не разрешило.

Comment: При определенных условиях - это возможно, рут, то приложение должно быть обязательно запущено именно в активити с нужным экраном(чтобы долго не возиться ) и т.д.